# Photoshop Disregards the invisible margins

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-lightroom

I created a signature logo with illustrator and Digital Signature on mobile and all was well and save.
Problem: When trying to place embed the logo onto an image, then using the align functions with an image that has been '**Exported** after Edit with **Photoshop**', the invisible margins of the logo are disregarded, throwing the text directly to the edges of the photo. [image]
However, when I try to do the same with an image that has been '**Exported** with **Lightroom**' then the invisible margins are regarded and the logo has some breathing space around the edges of the photo. 
[image]

All images are exported to JPEGS high quality, so formats are all same. Whats the difference between Lightroom & Photoshop export methods and how can I solve this issue? I will be exporting lots of my images with photoshop and I need to know how to solve this problem to make exports in batch quicker & Easier.

Comment: Every time I see this when it gets bumped by community, the transparency grid tablecloth puts my brain in a knot.

Answer (score 0):

For Illustrator artwork to be placed into Photoshop, 
if the desire is to retain whitespace from AI.....

You'll need to add a no fill, no stroke, rectangle around the AI artwork in Illustrator. (Often a rectangle the same size as the artboard in AI) Photoshop will then use that "hollow" rectangle as image dimensions when importing. Otherwise, Photoshop merely imports AI artwork based onthe bounding area of the artwork itself.

Comment: Awesome great will try that. However, I added a no fill, no stroke, rectangle around the AI artwork in Photoshop. I will try that in AI but I'm still confused as to why photoshop does that. 
Maybe i was not clear enough or i typed it out in a confusing way.

I'm trying to export only with photoshop now, so when i place the logo on an image that i previously exported with lightroom, there is the breathing space, but when exporting an image that was previously edited/and or exported with photoshop, there is no breathing space. What is it with photoshop exported images thats different from LR?

Comment: I'm not a Lightroom user... my *guess* would be that Lightroom reads the artboard for the AI artwork, Photoshop simply doesn't see the AI artboard.

Comment: okay thanks a lot. Problem solved. Thanks a lot!